# ASP Update Panel Stopped Working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Language: C#
Compiler: Visual Studio 2012
O/S: Windows 7 Home Premium

I have been using an `UpdatePanel` on my **Content** page for a while now, to update an Image based on text in a text box.
It all worked, up until now. Currently, the page does a full reload to display the image, instead of a partial post-back.

**.aspx code**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgProfilePicture" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtImageLocation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" MaxLength="1000" CssClass="styleTextBoxCenter" Width="170px" OnTextChanged="txtImageLocation_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <div style="padding-left: 4px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblImageUrl" runat="server" Text="Image URL" CssClass="styleLabelWatermark"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtImageLocation" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.cs code**

```
protected void txtImageLocation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtImageLocation.Text))
        {
            imgProfilePicture.ImageUrl = RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.CreateSignedUrl("http://i.minus.com/iNQ7wK2opRJT1.gif",
                                                                                    new ResizeSettings(
                                                                                        "width=183&format=png"));
            lblImageUrl.Text = "Image URL";
            return;
        }
        if (!@txtImageLocation.Text.StartsWith("http://"))
        {
            @txtImageLocation.Text = "http://" + @txtImageLocation.Text;
        }
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@txtImageLocation.Text);

        try
        {
            request.GetResponse();
            imgProfilePicture.ImageUrl = RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.CreateSignedUrl(@txtImageLocation.Text,
                                                                                    new ResizeSettings(
                                                                                        "width=183&s.roundcorners=10"));
            lblImageUrl.Text = "Image Verified";
            lblImageUrl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            imgProfilePicture.ImageUrl =
                RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.CreateSignedUrl(
                    "http://i.minus.com/ibwhXZ9wLo1mOz.jpg",
                    new ResizeSettings("width=183&s.roundcorners=10"));
            lblImageUrl.Text = "Invalid URL";
            lblImageUrl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            txtImageLocation.Focus();
        }
    }
```

I cant think of anything that I've changed, and the **Master** page still has a `ScriptManager` on.

Comment: check your error console first it gives any error ??

Comment: No errors given at all, only a few messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, all functionality is lost on an `UpdatePanel` if you set a "Global" Routein your `Global.asax`.

The issue started when I added `routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}", "~/{address}.aspx");`.

Upon removing, the ajax panels worked.